# How can I get the variables from JSON array in external js file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I got an external JS file which includes JSON array and functions helps me to pick a random set of variables. When I tried to generate the result in the main HTML file, nothing showed in the p tag. Am I mismatching any objects or variables?

Short Example of HTML file in body section

```
<p id="result"></p>
<script src="myJSfile.js" type="text/javascript">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = lottery(selected.name + selected.age);
</script>
```

Short Example of External JS file

```
function lottery() {
var from, to, selected=new Array();
var person=
    [
     {"name":"Georgia","age":"45"},
     {"name":"John","age":"38"},
     {"name":"Michael","age":"29"},
    ];
    if (arguments[0] == "all") {
      from=0;
      to=person.length;
    }
    else {
      from=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
      to=Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
    }
    for (i=0; i<to; i++) {
        selected[i]=person[from];
        from=(from+1)%3;
    }
    return selected;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `from`, `to` and `selected` variables are not visible outside the function just bring this line `var from, to, selected=new Array();` out of the function and it should work.

**All**

```js
var from, to, selected = new Array();
lottery('all');
for(var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += selected[k].name + " " + selected[k].age+'<br />';
}

function lottery() {
var person =
    [
     {"name":"Georgia","age":"45"},
     {"name":"John","age":"38"},
     {"name":"Michael","age":"29"},
    ];
    
    if (arguments[0] == "all") {
      from = 0;
      to = person.length;
    }
    else {
      from = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
      to = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < to; i++) {
        selected[i] = person[from];
        from = (from+1)%3;
    }
    
    return selected;
    
   }
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

**Random**

```js
var from, to, selected = new Array();
lottery('all');
for(var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++){
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += selected[k].name + " " + selected[k].age+'<br />';
}

function lottery() {
var person =
    [
     {"name":"Georgia","age":"45"},
     {"name":"John","age":"38"},
     {"name":"Michael","age":"29"},
    ];
    
    if (arguments[0] == "alla") {
      from = 0;
      to = person.length;
    }
    else {
      from = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
      to = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < to; i++) {
        selected[i] = person[from];
        from = (from+1)%3;
    }
    
    return selected;
    
   }
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thx @Muhammad. I tried. It seems worked but I still could not get the value from JSON given. I excepted as [John 38] but it returned as [object Object]. Maybe there is still something wrong in the innerHTML part. Almost done anyway.

Comment: Try to get the value like `selected[0].name`

Comment: sadly it does not change anything... should I take away the blankets of lottery ?

Comment: @JoeyU Please see my answer I have added an example, if it solves the problem don't forget to mark it as accepted. :-)

Comment: AWESOME. it works! thx so much. So, adding an extra variable k to define selected is the key.

Comment: @JoeyU I am glade that my solution was helpful for you. The `k` variable is just a counter that will be incremented on each iteration of loop, since the objects are stored in an array that's why we need to get each object using the loop and we used `k` as the counter to keep trace of each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code, please check, this should work

```
<p id="result"></p>
<script src="stackoverflow.js" type="text/javascript">
<script>
 (function() {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = lottery('all');
 })();
</script>
```

and in your external js

```
function lottery() {
var from;
var to; 
var selected=new Array();
var person=
[
 {"name":"Georgia","age":"45"},
 {"name":"John","age":"38"},
 {"name":"Michael","age":"29"},
];
if (arguments[0] == "all") {
  from=0;
  to=person.length;
}
else {
  from=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  to=Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
}
for (i=0; i<to; i++) {
    selected[i]=person[from];
    from=(from+1)%3;
}
return selected;
}
```

Comment: Thx @sanjay. It does shows somthing, not grabbing the exact value from JSON though. 
      Shown as [object Object],[object Object] not [John 38] that thing.  
I think I got the direction.

Comment: @JoeyU its showing [object Object] because lottery function returns selected as object, so try to get value from it.. like selected[0].name.
and if this answer solved your problem then please accept it

Comment: thx for the tips. I think that is the reason. selected[0].name is not working though. I checked with inserting the same set of JSON in HTML file directly and then something like person[0].name works properly...*sighs*